# Deploying a BreezeJS using EntityFramework and WebAPI

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am trying to deploy an application created using Breezejs and EntityFramework using the Breeze WebAPI. When I run it in my development environment it runs perfectly, but the minute I upload it to our server I get the following error "Error: Metadata query failed for: ../api/Entity/Metadata; Not Found" when I try and make a call.

In my development environment if I go to "localhost:59510/api/Entity/Metadata" I can see the xml displayed, but if I go to "www.example.com/api/Entity/Metadata" I get the error.

Am I missing a dll somewhere? Is it an error with my configuration in breezejs, web api's or with EntityFramework?

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: are you sure if you have the dll of Entity Frameowrk in your release?

Comment: I am suspecting some kind of routing problem. What does the network traffic from your browser say? What URL is composed? Can you add a dummy method to your controller and hit that (put a breakpoint on that method too)?

Comment: Yes, the EntityFramework dll is in the release. Will attempt to add the dummy method today

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing something.  Check the event viewer on the deployment machine. Could also be missing the breeze controller dlls